# Sql get top row for each type

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `WorkLog(personId number, actionType number, doneOn timeStamp)`, now how can i get the most recent action for each person.

the data will be like

```
p1 a1 timestamp1
p1 a2 timestamp2
p2 a1 timestamp3
p2 a3 timestamp4
p3 a1 timestamp5
```

the output should be

```
p1 a2 timestamp2
p2 a1 timestamp3
p3 a1 timestamp5
```

the database is DB2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "greatest n per group" query. According to [here](http://cmsaville.ca/documents/MiscDocs/TopNQueries.pdf) the below should work in DB2

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personId ORDER BY doneOn DESC) RN
FROM WorkLog
)
SELECT personId , actionType , doneOn 
FROM T
WHERE RN=1
```